# How to assign a specific value to sys.stdin?

Tags: python, stdin, python-2.x

I'm using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from io import StringIO

#data = sys.stdin.readlines()
sys.stdin = """
hello I feel good
how are you?
where have you been?
"""
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

When i run the above code, the print line prints out each character of the texts assigned to `sys.stdin`.  It prints one character per line:

```
h
e
l
l
o

I

....truncated
```

I'm trying to get the output to be as it was stored in `sys.stdin`, it should look like this:

```
hello I feel good
how are you?
where have you been?
```

Comment: Assigning a string to `sys.stdin` is utterly insane.  You've broken Python by doing this, as it expects that name to refer to a *file-like object*, on which it can call methods such as `.read()` or `.readline()`. If you want to do something with your string a line at a time, do `for line in myString.splitlines():` for example - no need to screw up the `sys` module in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
from io import StringIO
import sys

data = u"""\
hello I feel good
how are you?
where have you been?
"""

sys.stdin = StringIO(data)

for line in sys.stdin:
    print line.rstrip()
```

Output:

```
hello I feel good
how are you?
where have you been?
```

Comment: suppose the content of `data` is an environment variable.  How do I store its content in data.  The closest I got was `print(os.environ['EvanT'])` but when I put that in data, it just prints the actual text `print(os.environ['EvanT'])`.  Not the content of the `EvanT` variable.

Comment: Something like `StringIO(os.environ['EvanT'] + '\n')` ought to work.

Comment: I get the following error: `TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str`.  How do i fix?

Comment: `StringIO(os.environ['EvanT'] + u'\n')`

Answer (score 1):

content of the dabba.txt file:

```
hello I feel good
how are you?
where have you been?
```

This is the code in the del.py file

```
import sys
datq=sys.stdin.readlines()
for line in datq:
    print(line)
```

from command line in ubuntu 18.04:

```
cat dabba.txt | python del.py
```

The out put of the above code is:

```
hello I feel good

how are you?

where have you been?
```

Comment: Why did you import StringIO?

Comment: @KirkStrauser sorry copy paste problem from question.